# What algorithm use for calculate edge betweeness in girvan Newman community detection?

Tags: graph

I just newbie in community detection

I have read paper about girvan Newman for community detection

In step edge betweeness, for calculate highest edge betweeness based one shortes path, but I don't understand, what algorithm use for find Shortest Path in girvan Newman? I have read another paper, it's used Brandes algorithm.. My question is, what difference Brandes algorithm and dijkstra algorithm?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, I implemented once Newman Girvan.

To compute the betweeness, you have to solve the all-pairs shortest path problem. If I remember correctly, in the paper they refer to the `fast Newman algorithm`, but I never found anything about it.

However, to solve this problem, the most common approaches are running Dijkstra on all edges (if the graph is sparse), or using Floyd-Warshall algorithm (if it is dense).

In order to make it efficient, you should update the betweeness of nodes while computing the paths, and not iterate over all the paths after they've been found.

Comment: By default, girvan Newman use dijkstra? Or use fast Newman algorithm?

Comment: I don't think there is a default algorithm, it depends of the graph and performances you want.

Comment: But, when I use dijkstra for girvan Newman, it's make sense right?